# How did the New Republic identify the Razor Crest?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In S02E02 of *The Mandalorian*, the Razor Crest is "pulled over" by New Republic traffic cops, who manage to get Mando to turn on his transponder. From this they determine that the Razor Crest was involved in the prison breakout in Season 1.

The question is, how?

The whole point of using the Razor Crest was that it was off the registry and it obviously wasn't broadcasting during the raid. Also, on approach (and, I assume, departure) they took a path which kept the ship in the prison barge's blind spot and jammed its transmissions, so how did they recognize it?

Answer (score -2):

The presumption is that the prison frigate may have scanned or had video footage of the Razor Crest on approach.  We'll see if Jon Favreau or Dave confirms...